Run command in newly open windows terminal tab using rust
I'm trying to write a rust script to open multiple tabs using rust.
When opening the tab, I want to run the command passed to the function in that new tab
What's the simplest way to do it?
I'm using windows terminal, with git bash.
An exemple of a command I'm trying to run is: npm run dev
My Code:
fn open_tab(tab_name: &str, directory: &str, command: Option&lt;&str>, color: Option&lt;&str>) {
    let mut cmd = Command::new("wt");

    // Add tab options
    cmd.args(&[
        "-w",
        "0", // Use the current window
        "--title",
        tab_name, // Tab title
        "--startingDirectory",
        directory, // Start in the specified directory
    ]);

    // Add tab color if specified
    if let Some(tab_color) = color {
        cmd.args(&["--tabColor", tab_color]);
    }


    // Execute the command
    match cmd.output() {
        Ok(_) => println!("Opened tab: {}", tab_name),
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Failed to open tab {}: {}", tab_name, e),
    }
}


From Windows terminal command line arguments it looks you would pass the command as an unnamed parameter
